# find the voltage and current of inductors and capacitors

Tags: capacitor, inductor

I have a questions where I am trying to find the voltage and current across the inductors and capacitors under DC conditions in a circuit shown below.

[image]

I currently have found the current and voltage across the inductors to be 12 A and 12 V for the 1H  assuming that the voltage supplied to the inductor is the same as the voltage across which results in the current being 12 A. However when I solved for the 2H inductor I was not sure if I should solve for the current across the resistor first since in an LR circuit the currents are equal. Can someone help clear that up for me.

Comment: You have said a lot of things that make no sense.  Why don't you show the calculations you have made.

Comment: @jwh20 I figured it out i just had to take step back and look at it in a different way

Comment: At steady-state conditions (after enough time has passed that everything has settled), all ideal capacitors are open-circuit and all ideal inductors are short-circuit.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5SCwN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is what your DC equivalent circuit looks like.  Any questions?